# How do I switch to a new local git repository using egit on Eclipse for Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, egit

I am new to Eclipse and git and recently set up a repository on a network drive which is now being shared with someone else. Consequently I want to add my own local repository between me and the networked repository. How should I go about creating the local respoitory and switching across to it, whilst still being able to push to the networked repository?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by cloning the networked repository using

```
git clone <network repo path>
```

Do this in the location you want your local repository. C:\gitRepo or whereever else you want it from the command prompt. You can now commit to your local repository and push to the network repo or origin whenever you want.

You can find basic git commands here http://rogerdudler.github.com/git-guide/

EDIT

Just saw that you tagged this with eclipse and egit, If you want to do this with eclipse, you can click import and "import projects from git" and select URI, You can then provide the network path and select where you want to clone it, Refer to http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Cloning_remote_Repositories for more information